# Pandas for each row in some columns based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a DataFrame that has missing values in one or more columns, and I am trying to lookup the missing values based on the values in two other columns for the same record (i.e., fill `city_name` and `city_id` columns based on the coordinates in `lat` and `long` columns.)

| city_name | city_id | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | -121.77 | 37.24 |
| NaN | NaN | -122.77 | 38.24 |
| NaN | NaN | -123.77 | 39.24 |
| new york | c1 | -121.77 | 37.24 |
| paris | c2 | -122.77 | 38.24 |
| london | c3 | -123.77 | 39.24 |

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `groupby` and `fillna`:

```
df = df.fillna(df.groupby(["lat", "long"]).transform("first"))

>>> df

  city_id city_name     lat   long
0      c1  new york -121.77  37.24
1      c2     paris -122.77  38.24
2      c3    london -123.77  39.24
3      c1  new york -121.77  37.24
4      c2     paris -122.77  38.24
5      c3    london -123.77  39.24
```